# Error installing the "tidyverse" package and loading it

Tags: tidyverse

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/tidyverse_2.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 430680 bytes (420 KB)
downloaded 420 KB

Trying to load the package, I got the below error message.

library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
.onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
call: NULL
error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
there is no package called ‘colorspace’
```

I am new to learning R, please assist me resolve this issue so I could move on with my learning.

I tried loading the package after i got a successful package download notice in the console but the package would not load.

Comment: try `install.packages("colorspace")`

Comment: `Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed`
Google for "Rtools", download and install it, and try running the `install.packages("tidyverse")` again